# Access: Split File Name Import into several columns

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, vba

I apologize if this seems like a double post but I can't seem to find a solution for my project. I am working in Access creating a simple database. I have a Form that allows users to build names based on the file they are naming. They use the comboboxes to make selections. We have a naming protocol that I am trying to make easier to utilize.
[Image of my Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIAzM.png)

I want to create a subform that will filter existing file names I import with VBA. What I need in my subform is the name and path of possible existing  files so the user can find it on the network. I got the code from the below person to harvest the file names. The code is long so I didn't add it but I can if needed but it work great!

h1ttp://allenbrowne.com/ser-59alt.html

With this code I now have my existing file names in a table
[Image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDBak.png)
Follow me so far?
I thought that would be the hardest part but not a chance. now I'm trying to split the name up into columns so I can filter by the selections in the comboboxs.

```
Example name

12-CW-Base-Blind Corner-UH.rfa

column 1 = 12
column 2 = CW
Column 3 = Base
Column 4 = Blind Corner
Column 5 = UH
```

Something like this.
User selects 12 in the Master Format Combobox.
The subform table now only shows file names that begin with 12.
User selects CW in the next Combobox
The subform table now only shows file names that have 12-CW in the beginning.
etc.

From my research there are a couple ways to do this.

1. First is by adding Left, Mid, Right directly in a query. Benefits to this is not having to store old data and it seams more flexible.
2. Second is to create a module that loops through the records and adds them to a table.
3. Use some kind of filter that updates the subform as the selections are made. This doesn't even store the data in another table.

I need advice on which direction to go and how to get there. I can share the methods I have explored already if that helps. Most of them are using 1 and 2. If you have read this far thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a small helper function:

```
Public Function FileNamePart(ByVal FileName As String, NameItem Integer) As String

    ' Strip extension, then pick part.
    FileNamePart = Split(Split(FileName, ".")(0), "-")(NameItem - 1)

End Function
```

Then create a query:

```
Select 
    *, 
    FileNamePart([FName], 1) As Part1,
    FileNamePart([FName], 2) As Part2,
    FileNamePart([FName], 3) As Part3,
    FileNamePart([FName], 4) As Part4,
    FileNamePart([FName], 5) As Part5
From
    Files
```

Then you can filter on this.

Comment: I like it! Clean and simple. Thank you so much Gustav! Ill let you know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

1. this gets really difficult with more than 3 parts unless filenames have a fixed length for each part as well as the same number of parts
2. saving search results to another table is overkill
3. dynamic filter parameter in query: `LIKE "*'" Forms!formname!tbxParameter "'*"` would find all records containing value typed into textbox, I suppose progressive filtering could be coded in VBA but I have never done that

Comment: Thanks June7! I'm not sure how the dynamic filter works. Do I do this for each column or something else? Are there any variables in there that I need to adjust for my use? Thanks!

Comment: The dynamic filter would go under the FName field.